# Magento 2 Which Index should set "Index By Schedule" or "Update On Save" for performance purpose?

Tags: magento2, indexing, indexer

I have a site with Magento 2.3.3 version with over 10000 catalog products.
For performance purposes which Indexer should set "**Update on Save**" or "**Update On Schedule**".

Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

All Indexer should be set "Update On Schedule". If you wanna update at that times you changes can run magento cli reindex via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

**Update on Save**: The index is set to update whenever a change is saved form backend Or from API

**Update on Schedule**: The index is set to update on schedule according to a cron job. It is recommended set indexers to **Update on Schedule**.

To Optimize indexing process, I recommend you to check below post as I refer it multiple times:

https://medium.com/@royandre/how-we-reduced-the-magento-2-price-reindex-process-from-hours-to-minutes-and-how-you-can-too-51744c6571b4